# How to save the state of dialog box after it has been dismissed

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have Dialog box to enter pin. if user enters the invalid pin it starts the timer.
When i dismiss the dialog box on back button and then again opens the dialog box on item click it resets it states and timer is gone.Its a pin dialog box . when user enters the wrong pin a timer starts under pin layout such that he cannot enter pin for that particular time for eg: 30 seconds. While 30 seconds count down is running and i close the dialog box and immediately open it again timer is gone and it has new state.

***How to save the state of dialog box after dismiss such that timer runs in background and when i open it again it shows the state where timer is running? need help regarding this***

**onItemClick it opens dialog box():**

```
lockCardView.setOnClickListener {
             showEnterPinDialog(Input.fromNullable(ItemList))
                            }

fun showEnterPinDialog(ItemList: Input<ArrayList<String>>) {
        var dialog = EnterPinDialog(activity.requireActivity(),Repository, ItemList)
        dialog.show()
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    }
```

**DialogBox code:**

```
class EnterPinDialog(
    context: Context,
    var Repository: ItemRepository,
    var ItemList: Input<ArrayList<String>>
): Dialog(context) {

    lateinit var dataBind : EnterPinDialogBinding

    var itemPinList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var confirm_pin :String? = null
    var sum = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataBind = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.enter_pin_dialog, null, false)
        setContentView(dataBind.root)
        dataBind.materialTextView53.visibility = View.GONE
        dataBind.pinView.transformationMethod = AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod()
        dataBind.pinView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
//                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
//                TODO("Not yet implemented")
                confirm_pin = s.toString()
                val epin = md5(confirm_pin!!)
                for (ls in itemPinList.indices){
                    if (s!!.length>5) {
                        if (epin.equals(itemPinList.get(ls).toString())) {
                            setItemLockAPi(ItemList, false)

                         
                                    dismiss()
                                }
                            }, 1500)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sum++
                            dataBind.pinView.setLineColor(
                                ContextCompat.getColor(
                                    dataBind.root.context,
                                    R.color.red
                                )
                            )
                            dataBind.materialTextView53.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            dataBind.pinView.text?.clear()
                            dataBind.attemptsLeft.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            dataBind.attemptsLeft.text = "${3 - sum} attempts left"
                            if(sum == 3){
                                dataBind.attemptsLeft.visibility = View.GONE
                                dataBind.materialTextView53.visibility = View.GONE
                                dataBind.failedAttempts.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                dataBind.pinView.clearFocus()
                                dataBind.pinView.isEnabled = false
                                dataBind.timerThirty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                                    // Callback function, fired on regular interval
                                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                                        dataBind.timerThirty.text = "${millisUntilFinished / 1000} Seconds"
                                    }

                                    // Callback function, fired
                                    // when the time is up
                                    override fun onFinish() {
//                                    textView.setText("done!")
                                        dataBind.pinView.isEnabled = true
                                        dataBind.failedAttempts.visibility = View.GONE
                                        dataBind.pinView.setLineColor(
                                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                                dataBind.root.context,
                                                R.color.white
                                            )
                                        )
                                        dataBind.timerThirty.visibility = View.GONE
                                        sum = 0
                                    }
                                }.start()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
//                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

        dataBind.backPin.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the 'state' of a dialog box?. And for what a timer is needed?

Comment: @blackapps when user enters the wrong pin a timer starts under pin layout such that he cannot enter pin for that particular time for eg: 30 seconds. While 30 seconds count down is running and i close the dialog box and immediately open it again timer is gone and it has new state. i have updated the question as well.

Comment: You need to put countdown timer outside the dialog. You can create a viewmodel with your activity as the lifecycle owner if you don't have it yet. Then put the timer inside the viewmodel and let it emit the countdown livedata. Your dialog can then just observe the livedata.

Comment: Using saved state bundle is a handy option unless you want it to persist when your application is killed. If you want it to persist, (to me it may be unnecessary in this case) then you can use shared preferences.

Comment: I stil have no idea what you consider the state of your box.

Comment: @blackapps stte of my dialog box is when timer is running.(countdown from 30 sec to 0 sec)When i dismiss the the box ,the state of the box refreshes immediately and t starts from beginning no timer is there still i have closed the box at 24 sec and immediately opened it.

Comment: @Kozmotronik can you provide me with a code snippet or example how can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

The timer is reset because you have `0` as the default value for the timer. So when the dialog is being created, you don't give the timer a value instead it has its default value `0`.

When a timer starts due to incorrect PIN entered, save the timer value as a `state` that keeps incrementing by the second in your `ViewModel`. Then when creating the dialog, check your `ViewModel` to see if the `state` has a value already. If yes, set the dialog timer's value to it.

Don't forget to reset the state when the timer is exhausted (when the timer counts down to `zero`).   :)